# Communicating HART-IP from Java

Tags: java, network-programming, iot

In an IoT project I am forced to communicate via HART-IP with an measuring device from my java component. I am a total newbie to HART. I know that is (traditional) HART uses 4-20mA signal modulation to transfer additional information. HART-IP is leveraging HART to Ethernet. I also know that are DTDs, DTMs and FDTs...so far so good.

But I haven't found any resources describing how to start using HART-IP, not to mention in combination with Java.

I would assume, that with HART-IP I don't have to care about signal modulation anymore but just "firing" my commands and receive the response.

Has anyone a good starting point for the work with HART-IP?

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HART-IP is a protocol developed and controlled by the [FieldComm Group](http://www.fieldcommgroup.org).  It's used to communicate to HART field devices via a network-connected WirelessHART gateway or other HART-IP enabled instruments.

In order to get the specifications for the protocol, you need to either become a member of FCG (expensive, but comes with tech support) or purchase them for $1000 (still expensive, but not nearly as much).

You are correct in that you do not have to worry about the 4-20mA signaling modulation with HART-IP, but you will be responsible for setting up the TCP/IP or UDP sockets to the WirelessHART gateway and constructing the frames in accordance with the HART-IP protocol.  These are essentially the standard HART commands wrapped in HART-IP-specific Ethernet packets.

However you choose to obtain the specifications, you will have a fair amount of development work ahead of you.  From what you are describing, you are trying to develop a HART host application.  There are no APIs or DLLs available for HART-IP so you'll be building from the ground up.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped to hear but it confirmed my fears.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a HART master(host) slack, you have 2 solutions:
 1. Develop code all by your self
 2. Buy it from HART authorized companies which most of them are in Europe
If you wanna do it by your self you need to get specification documents from Field com.

Best Regards